# Автоматическое создание и задание значения свойств для страниц при их создании

Tags: битрикс

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите есть ли возможность автоматического создания свойств и их значений при создании страницы, суть такая: при создании страницы у нее должно автоматически прописываться свойство 'Ответственный', этому свойству присваивается значение, имя текущего пользователя. Есть ли такая возможность, и возможно ли редактировать стандартную форму конструктора создания страницы, так как по мимо автоматического задания автора, нужно еще чтобы было поле с типом календарь. Может кто подскажет куда копать, может есть событие 'создание страницы'? В модуле журнал событий создание страниц логируется, но я не смог найти что это за события, и можно ли его как то использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я неправильно понял, но для этого должны помочь шаблоны (Активный шаблон), вот ссылка на офф. документацию https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=3090#active_shablon

Выдержка оттуда:

**Активный шаблон** - это шаблон, который при создании страницы (раздела) запрашивает дополнительные данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример активного шаблона размещён в виде папки `\bitrix\templates\.default\page_templates\forum` в дефолтном шаблоне дистрибутива "1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом".

В файле `\bitrix\templates\.default\page_templates\forum\template.php` можно посмотреть пример оформления шаблона и создать по его образцу собственный.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. Я знаю про шаблоны страниц. Ваш совет подошел бы если бы мне нужно было передать параметры в заранее созданный компонент по шаблону. А мне нужно создавать новые свойства самой страницы и сохранять их, на пример дефолтное свойство Заголовок страницы, только в моем случае свойство должно создаваться и получать значение автоматически, без участия пользователя.